# Swift iOS -NSMutableAttributedString Not Presenting ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsmutablestring

I'm adding a NSMutableAttributedString to a textView and I when I click the tappableString I want to present a new vc. The vc isn't being presented and I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong at.

I set the textView delegate and use the textView's `...shouldInteractWithURL` and inside there I check to see that the url's absolute string matches the `NSLinkAttributeName's` value which is "doSomething" but the vc isn't appearing.

**Where am I going wrong at?**

```
class FirstController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    fileprivate let textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        return textView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.delegate = self

        configureTextView()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        textView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
    }

    func configureTextView(){

        //textView anchors are set

        let firstPlainSent = "Read this first.\n"
        let secondPlainSent = "Read this second.\n"

        plainSentAttr = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]

        let firstSent = NSAttributedString(string: firstPlainSent, attributes: plainSentAttr)
        let secondSent = NSAttributedString(string: secondPlainSent, attributes: plainSentAttr)

        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        mutableAttributedString.append(firstSent)
        mutableAttributedString.append(secondSent)

        let tappableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Click here to present the SecondVC\n\n")
        tappableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)!, range: NSMakeRange(0, (tappableString.length)))
        tappableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSMakeRange(0, (tappableString.length)))
        tappableString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range:  NSMakeRange(0,tappableString.length))
        tappableString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSMakeRange(0, tappableString.length))
        tappableString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "doSomething", range: NSMakeRange(0, (tappableString.length)))

        mutableAttributedString.append(tappableString)

        textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
    }


    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

        // I also tried URL.scheme
        if URL.absoluteString == "doSomething"{

            let secondVC = SecondController()
            let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
            present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your code to a new project and in my case the new VC appears! Is there something wrong with some other part of your code?

Comment: @AndréSlotta thanks for the help. There’s nothing that I know of that is wrong and my anchors are fine because I can see the text view and the text. It’s strange it works for you and not me? I’ll double check again.

Comment: @AndréSlotta the problem was I used an older version of the textView's method. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad i could "help" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using the older method signature of the textView's delegate method:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool{

}
```

Once I used autocomplete and the newer method signature appeared everything worked fine:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to instantiate a view controller using its Storyboard name

here "Main" is storyboard name.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondController") as! SecondController
```

So final code will be like,

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondController") as! SecondController

let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks but it’s programmatic. I’m not using Storyboards

Comment: btw you shouldn't use UIStoryboard as the constant's name. It should be lowercase and not begin with UI. Something like this would be more suitable: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil), let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController...

Comment: I tried your code, it works fine. It shows black screen, then I just added background color, that also works fine.

Comment: the problem was I used an older version of the textView's method. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was messing around with this for hours trying to figure out the problem. Sometimes it’s the smallest things. . Thanks again and enjoy your holidays! 